# Combine multiple Heatmap generated by seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

Suppose a data set with correlation between 3 variables. The correlation is measured over 2 different periods.
The data is in form:

```
df1
    A   B   C
A   NaN 0.1 0.2
B   0.7 NaN 0.5
C   0.6 0.4 NaN

df2
    A   B   C
A   NaN 1   0.5
B   0.5 NaN 0.6
C   0.6 0.2 NaN
```

The objective is to generate heat map. I tried this

```
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df1)
ax2 = sns.heatmap(df2)
```

but this gives me individual heatmaps as shown in part 1 of figure.

So as shown in this poor diagram, on horizontal axis, I would like to divided the variables by seasons. How do I achieve this?

[FIGURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBEPd.png)

Comment: you posted no part 1 of no figure, neither any poor diagram...

Comment: fixed the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about appending both dataframes into one and applying a multiindex:

```
df = df1.append(df2)
#     0    1    2
#A  NaN  0.1  0.2
#B  0.7  NaN  0.5
#C  0.6  0.4  NaN
#A  NaN  1.0  0.5
#B  0.5  NaN  0.6
#C  0.6  0.2  NaN

iterables = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['df1', 'df2']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['Var', 'season'])
dfm = pd.DataFrame(df.sort_index().values, index=index)
#              0    1    2
#Var season               
#A   df1     NaN  0.1  0.2
#    df2     NaN  1.0  0.5
#B   df1     0.7  NaN  0.5
#    df2     0.5  NaN  0.6
#C   df1     0.6  0.4  NaN
#    df2     0.6  0.2  NaN

sns.heatmap(dfm, annot=True)
```

[image]